# Need assistance with if statement in Blackjack game

Tags: javascript, if-statement, blackjack

I am working on my first black jack game and I keep getting confused by the simplest thing. The problem is in my if statement I say this :

```
if ( cardsinhand < 7 && newcard != firstcard && newcard != secondcard )
```

and when I press the hit me button it will deal me the same card over and over again. Here is my function. I need the info in the if statement to be true and then execute, otherwise just not execute.

```
cardsinhand = 2
firstcard = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000 % 52)
secondcard = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000 % 52)
newcard = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000 % 52)

function hitCard()
{
  if ( cardsinhand < 7 && newcard != firstcard && newcard != secondcard )
  {
    document.images[cardsinhand].src = "http://www.biogow/images/cards/gbCard" + newcard + ".gif"

    cardsinhand++
  }
}
```

any idea why this isnt working right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not actually a problem with your `if` statement itself. It appears that this:

```
newcard = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000 % 52)
```

is being done *once* rather than every time you hit. That means you *will* get the same card over and over.

You should probably recalculate a new card every time you perform a hit operation.

---

You should probably also look into *how* you're generating cards. Normally, you would use a deck (containing one or more "real" decks) so that the probabilities change as cards are removed, just like in real life.

That would also fix any skewing problem from using `* 1000 % 52` which would tend to prefer cards at one end of the "deck".

Comment: Thank you that was my problem after all

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are only ever generating `newcard` once, outside of the function body. What you want is for the new card to be generated each time you call the function, and so this line: `newcard = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000 % 52)` should be inside the function, like so:

```
cardsinhand = 2
firstcard = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000 % 52)
secondcard = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000 % 52)


function hitCard()
{
    var newcard = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000 % 52)
    if ( cardsinhand < 7 && newcard != firstcard && newcard != secondcard )
    {
        document.images[cardsinhand].src = "http://www.biogow/images/cards/gbCard"+newcard+".gif"

         cardsinhand++ 
    }
}
```

Also for what it's worth, if you're just starting out you might want to look into using an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) for storing the cards of your hand. What's going to happen to that `if` condition when your newcard could be the first card, the second card *or* the third card?